# How to remove git push permission?

Tags: git, github

How can I remove the permission of `git push`?

I've tried reinstalling git and deleting `.ssh` folder and `.gitconfig` file on my windows machine.

But I still find I'm able to `git push` to my repository on github.

The reason I want to do this is because the laptop I'm using now will be given to another coworker in my company after a few days.

This is what I get now:

```
git push
Everything up-to-date
```

I want it to be:

```
git push 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It seems that the public key stored on github is not used after I type `git push`.

Are my github account and password stored somewhere in the laptop?

The following is the output of `git config --list --show-origin`

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    filter.lfs.required=true
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    credential.helper=manager
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=false
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.symlinks=false
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://github.com/lyenliang/Test.git
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
file:.git/config        branch.master.remote=origin
file:.git/config        branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Maybe I can find some clues from `credential.helper=manager`.

Comment: What is your repository? Do you work with github, gerrit or something else? Can you paste error which you've get from the server?

Comment: I work with github.

Comment: Go to your profile settings on GitHub -> SSH and GPG keys, and delete the key for the machine you want to unpair.

Comment: Update: delete all the keys and see what happens, you're not using them anyway. Are you signed in with the same creds on web and cli?

Comment: I've cleared all the credentials on my browser. I don't know to sign in with CLI.

Comment: Do you find a credential-helper here: `git config --list --show-origin`? Perhaps have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950/5784831)

Comment: @Christoph, Thank you. The credential is removed after I reboot the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The line `file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"    credential.helper=manager` tells you that a credentail manager is used.

You can see the different levels of config files in the output of `git config --list --show-origin`:

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config" --> global, user specific
file:"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig" --> system
file:.git/config --> local, user specific
```

From the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES)

> **$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig**
>     System-wide configuration file.
>   **$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config**
>     Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any
>   single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by
>   whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create this file
>   if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file
>   was added fairly recently.
>   **~/.gitconfig**
>   User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.
>   **$GIT_DIR/config**
>   Repository specific configuration file.

**Important:** Local settings always overwrite less local settings